# Calculating new angle after bounce

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm having a simple question about bouncing, but I can't seem to solve it.

I'm having an object that approaches a vector and collides.
Now I would like to calculate the new angle after the bounce.
I know the impact angle on the vector (for example 71°)

Simply doing the current angle minus the impact angle doesn't seem to work in all cases.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
best regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "approach a vector," but here's the general solution:

Let's say that your object is moving linearly along the velocity vector $v$. It hits some fixed object and bounces off, and you want to compute the new velocity $v'$.

First, compute where the moving object hits the fixed object, and calculate the *contact normal* $\hat{n}$: the vector perpendicular to the fixed object at the point of contact.

Now use the formula
$$v' = v - 2(\hat{n}\cdot v)\hat{n}.$$
What this does is reflect the velocity about the line (in 2D) or plane (in 3D) perpendicular to $\hat{n}$. This will ensure that the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection, and that tangential momentum is conserved.